# Word 2013 Appendix Page Numbering and Appendix Outline Styles

Tags: microsoft-word

I have appendices in my documents. Appendices are separated with Section Breaks (Next Page).

**Page Numbering:**
Within the Appendices, I need to automatically number each section with the letter of the appendix, then the number of the page, eg A-1, B-1...  How do I get both?

**Outline Styles:**
Within the Appendices I have Sections.  I would like to call the sections A.1, A.2, A.2.1, etc., and the same in each of the appendices.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create a suite of Appendix styles and apply the outline numbering you want (eg Appendix L1 would be set up as Appendix A, Appendix L2 would be set up as A.1 etc).

Then in your footer, you can use a STYLEREF field to get the "A" part of your "A-1" numbering.  Include the switches \n \t.  \n says display the "number" (which is Appendix A) and \t says suppress non-delimiter characters which hides the "Appendix" leaving you with just "A".

[image]
[image]
[image]